# Do paladins follow evil laws?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin, alignment

Lets say a paladin is in a town and the town has slavery or a racist law or something like that they know is evil. If they follow the law or let it continue that's evil but if they fight it that's chaotic. What would a paladin's code of honor tell them to do?

Comment: Voting to close as "opinion based", as this question appears to be off topic per our guidance on alignment questions: [Are questions about alignment on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5357)

Comment: Related: [When laws conflict what does a Lawful character do?](/questions/53257)

Comment: Hi, Foxx, unfortunately this kind of question tends to just generate arguments and opinion and so don't work on the site, as explained by the meta question Thomas Markov linked. While not the best first meeting with the site, welcome to it never the less :) You might want to take the [tour] as an introduction to what does work and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: For this particular question, I can recommend a traditional forum, see here for a curated list: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449)

Comment: @Foxx I understand the frustration, but not every question works here. You may have use of a traditional forum instead. As for this being closed, you may have use of [What does it mean for a question to be closed?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11165/52137). As for deleting your account, see your profile page

Comment: People are always getting posts closed here, especially new members until they get the hang of the rules, don't worry about it, it's not personal.  It's not like a usual forum where if you're breaking site rules enough to get posts closed you'll be in trouble with the mods, here they just see it as tidying up.  This site just has very strict rules about what is or isn't an allowed topic.